# Adding file to JEditorPane using Full Directory Path

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtree, jeditorpane

I have been searching for this for awhile now online and I have not been able to find any real information on it... I was wondering is there anyway to open up a file(like a java file) from using the files full directory path?

I am currently add files to my JEditorPane using

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
jEditorPane.read(br, indexOfFile);
```

which is ok but it makes it alot more complicated to add files this way as i have chenged the design of my application to have a JTree and i am not able to get the index of the files correctly now!

So is there a way to add a file to a JEditorPane using the files path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a static method once and use it everywhere:

```
public static void loadTextFileIntoEditorPane(String filePath, JEditorPane editor) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    editor.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
}
```

Comment: I do have it, i will show my full code so...but how exactly do you display the file to the editor using the filepath?

Comment: but with the way i am doing it now, you need two arguments for the jEditorPane.read(Reader in, Object desc)... what do you add as the Object desc is my problem as that is currently the index of the file?

Comment: @flexinIT just added `setPage()` method.

Comment: Thanks a mil, worked like a charm... didnt know about .setPage() :)